# Normalise the sql query to return the SUM columns based on condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

For Below query I need to display the results based on the below checking 
qs13_b_BuildingInsuranceAmt sum should happen based on the below condition.

```
AND SP.Data.value('(/*/Answers/AnswersList/Entry[@key="as22_RightOfPledgeNum"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') = @AS22_RightOfPledgeNum
    AND SP.Data.value('(/*/Answers/AnswersList/Entry[@key="as18_BuildingRightOfPledge"]/value)[1]', 'bit') = 1
```

Similarly for other columns as like below ;

```
qs14_OutdoorEquipment --> AS19_OutdoorEquipmentRightOfPledge
qs15_EquipmentsMachinery --> AS20_EquipmentsMachineryRightOfPledge
qs16_MerchandiseProduct --> AS21_MerchandiseProductRightOfPledge
```

Below is the resultant query with full details.I need to sum the values based on the above condition for individual column.

```
DECLARE @LocationSubjectData table (
        ProposalId uniqueidentifier
        ,QL4_Num int
        ,SumOfQS13AndQS14 decimal
        ,SumOfQS15 decimal
        ,SumOfQS16 decimal
        ,SumOfQS13bAndQS14b decimal
        ,SumOfQS15b decimal
        ,SumOfQS16b decimal
    )
    INSERT INTO @LocationSubjectData
    SELECT
        Loc.ProposalId
        ,Loc.QL4_Num
        ,SUM(ISNULL(SP.Data.value('(/*/Answers/AnswersList/Entry[@key="qs13_Building"]/value)[1]', 'decimal'), 0) + ISNULL(SP.Data.value('(/*/Answers/AnswersList/Entry[@key="qs14_OutdoorEquipment"]/value)[1]', 'decimal'), 0))
        ,SUM(ISNULL(SP.Data.value('(/*/Answers/AnswersList/Entry[@key="qs15_EquipmentsMachinery"]/value)[1]', 'decimal'), 0))
        ,SUM(ISNULL(SP.Data.value('(/*/Answers/AnswersList/Entry[@key="qs16_MerchandiseProduct"]/value)[1]', 'decimal'), 0))
        ,SUM(ISNULL(SP.Data.value('(/*/Answers/AnswersList/Entry[@key="qs13_b_BuildingInsuranceAmt"]/value)[1]', 'decimal'), 0) + ISNULL(SP.Data.value('(/*/Answers/AnswersList/Entry[@key="qs14_b_OutdoorEquipmentInsuranceAmt"]/value)[1]', 'decimal'), 0))
        ,SUM(ISNULL(SP.Data.value('(/*/Answers/AnswersList/Entry[@key="qs15_b_EquipmentsMachineryInsuranceAmt"]/value)[1]', 'decimal'), 0))
        ,SUM(ISNULL(SP.Data.value('(/*/Answers/AnswersList/Entry[@key="qs16_b_MerchandiseProductInsuranceAmt"]/value)[1]', 'decimal'), 0))
    FROM @Locations Loc
    INNER JOIN SubProposal SP ON SP.MasterProposalId = Loc.ProposalId
    WHERE SP.EndEffectiveDate = @EndEffectiveDate
    AND ISNULL(SP.Data.value('(/*/IsRemovedByEndorsement)[1]', 'bit'), 0) = 0
    GROUP BY Loc.ProposalId, Loc.QL4_Num
```

Comment: What is the sp.data.value?

Comment: it's alias name for SubProposal table you can see in the query.

Comment: I'm struggling to visualize it. Could you add an example of what you want the output to look like?